# Nginx + Express - serve static files from Docker container

Tags: docker, express, nginx, server

I have an Express api and an Nginx together in a Docker Container. I want the Nginx to reverse proxy regular requests to the API, but I want it to serve the static files like images directly.

But I can't for the life of me seem to figure out the exact URI that I need to use here and the images keep 404-ing. Here's the docker-compose:

```
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api

  nginx-proxy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - api
```

And here's the nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    
    location /images/ {
        alias /public/images/;
        # THIS PART JUST DOESN'T WORK
    }
}
```

I've tried multiple URIs but I can't figure out the logic of this. How does the Nginx image access the files from the Express image? This is the error I get:

```
2024-01-07 00:00:00 nginx-proxy  | 2024/01/06 00:00:00 [error] 30#30: *4 open() "/public/images/test.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /images/test.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:2222/"
```

Edit: I should add that I did copy the images folder in the API Dockerfile, they are served when I query them through the API.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a file at `/public/images/test.png` in the Nginx image?

Comment: You need to `COPY` them in the proxy image's Dockerfile.

Comment: @DavidMaze I did that. The images are served fine when I query the api directly.

Comment: @HansKilian I'm expecting them to be in the Express image not Nginx. Because I copied them, the files are served through the Express so I know they are there.

Comment: But you say in your first paragraph that you want Nginx to serve static files directly. To do that, they need to be in the Nginx image.

Comment: @HansKilian Ah I see. I was assuming that I can access the Express image from the Nginx image. Is this not possible? So I actually have to copy the Express images folder into the Nginx root folder?

Comment: Containers are isolated from each other and can't access each others file systems. So if you want the Nginx container to serve the static files, you need to copy them into the Nginx image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shared with us the contents of your nginx Dockerfile, but it looks like you're never placing any content into the `/public/images` directory in the nginx container.

Rather than building the images into the container image, we can bind mount a local `images` directory into the container at runtime. This lets us use the stock nginx image, rather than needing to build our own.

Here's a slightly modified version of your Dockerfile that seems to work just fine:

```
services:
  angles-api:
    build:
      context: api
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sSf", "http://localhost:3000"]
      interval: "5s"
      retries: 3

  nginx-proxy:
    image: docker.io/nginx:mainline
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./images:/public/images
    depends_on:
      angles-api:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Where:

`api/Dockerfile` contains:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest

USER root
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl -sSfL -o /tmp/whoami.tar.gz https://github.com/traefik/whoami/releases/download/v1.10.1/whoami_v1.10.1_linux_amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar -C /usr/local/bin -xf /tmp/whoami.tar.gz whoami

ENV WHOAMI_PORT_NUMBER=3000
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/whoami"]
```

`./nginx.conf` contains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://angles-api:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /images/ {
        alias /public/images/;
    autoindex on;
    }
}
```

And `./images` contains:

```
total 160
-rw-r--r-- 1 lars lars 161352 Jan  6 21:15 uncle-deadly.png
```

---

With the above configuration, a request to `localhost:8080/images/` goes to the `/public/images` directory in the nginx container:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/images/
<html>
<head><title>Index of /images/</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Index of /images/</h1><hr><pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="uncle-deadly.png">uncle-deadly.png</a>                                   07-Jan-2024 02:15              161352
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

A request for any path not under `/images` goes to the API container:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/
Hostname: 8c7638b8d4c2
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 192.168.144.2
RemoteAddr: 192.168.144.3:39468
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.144.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.144.1
```

And:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/foo/bar
Hostname: 8c7638b8d4c2
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 192.168.144.2
RemoteAddr: 192.168.144.3:40144
GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.144.1
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.144.1
```

Note that in the above `compose.yaml`, we're using the long form of the `depends_on` option so that the nginx container doesn't start up until the api container is healthy. The older short form of the `depends_on` option is effectively useless, since it doesn't know anything about the state of the application running inside the container (so it doesn't prevent a dependent container from trying to make requests before the target container is ready).

---

All of the files referenced in this answer can be found online [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-77771399-nginx-proxy).